# Print a list of lists vertically

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that contains contains string that represent cards in a deck. I need to print the list vertically.

```
stacks = [['4C', 'QD', '9D', 'TD', 'JH', 'JD', '6C', 'AC', '3C', 'TS', 'TH'], ['AH', '2C', 'KD', '8C', '5C', '5H', '2D', '5D', '7C', 'AS', 'AD'], ['3S', 'KH', '3H', 'TC', 'QS', '4D', '7S', '7H', '9C', '4S'], ['JS', '7D', 'KC', 'QH', '6S', '6H', '8H', '8S', 'JC', '5S'], ['KS', '2S', 'QC', '4H', '6D', '9S', '2H', '8D', '3D', '9H']]
```

I need it to print like:

```
4C AH 3S JS KS
QD 2C KH 7D 2S
```

and continue on like that

Comment: I have tried nested loops and it will print the list but everything will be on a new line so after the first list is completely printed it will print the next list right below it. I need it to print beside it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
stacks = [['4C', 'QD', '9D', 'TD', 'JH', 'JD', '6C', 'AC', '3C', 'TS', 'TH'], ['AH', '2C', 'KD', '8C', '5C', '5H', '2D', '5D', '7C', 'AS', 'AD'], ['3S', 'KH', '3H', 'TC', 'QS', '4D', '7S', '7H', '9C', '4S'], ['JS', '7D', 'KC', 'QH', '6S', '6H', '8H', '8S', 'JC', '5S'], ['KS', '2S', 'QC', '4H', '6D', '9S', '2H', '8D', '3D', '9H']]
stacks = zip(*stacks)
print stacks
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[('4C', 'AH', '3S', 'JS', 'KS'), 
 ('QD', '2C', 'KH', '7D', '2S'), 
 ('9D', 'KD', '3H', 'KC', 'QC'), 
 ('TD', '8C', 'TC', 'QH', '4H'), 
 ('JH', '5C', 'QS', '6S', '6D'), 
 ('JD', '5H', '4D', '6H', '9S'), 
 ('6C', '2D', '7S', '8H', '2H'), 
 ('AC', '5D', '7H', '8S', '8D'), 
 ('3C', '7C', '9C', 'JC', '3D'), 
 ('TS', 'AS', '4S', '5S', '9H')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 rows are longer than the rest, so use `itertools.izip_longest()` instead of the standard `zip()` to preserve that data. I've used a fill value of `''` which is used for missing values in unequal length lists.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

stacks = [['4C', 'QD', '9D', 'TD', 'JH', 'JD', '6C', 'AC', '3C', 'TS', 'TH'], ['AH', '2C', 'KD', '8C', '5C', '5H', '2D', '5D', '7C', 'AS', 'AD'], ['3S', 'KH', '3H', 'TC', 'QS', '4D', '7S', '7H', '9C', '4S'], ['JS', '7D', 'KC', 'QH', '6S', '6H', '8H', '8S', 'JC', '5S'], ['KS', '2S', 'QC', '4H', '6D', '9S', '2H', '8D', '3D', '9H']]

for row in izip_longest(*stacks, fillvalue=''):
    print ' '.join(row)
```

Output:

```
4C AH 3S JS KS
QD 2C KH 7D 2S
9D KD 3H KC QC
TD 8C TC QH 4H
JH 5C QS 6S 6D
JD 5H 4D 6H 9S
6C 2D 7S 8H 2H
AC 5D 7H 8S 8D
3C 7C 9C JC 3D
TS AS 4S 5S 9H
TH AD
```

If you don't want the stray spaces on the last line:

```
for row in izip_longest(*stacks):
    print ' '.join(col for col in row if col is not None)
```

Here is a way to do it with nested loops only:

```
longest = max(len(row) for row in stacks)
for i in range(longest):
    for row in stacks:
            if i < len(row):
                    print row[i],
    print
```

Comment: I am getting an ImportError saying I cannot import izip_longest is this something I have to download separately? Do you know of a way to get that same output but with loops instead?

Comment: izip_longest is in itertools - it's a standard package. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: version 3.3.4 of Python in Wing IDE

Comment: I figured it out by searching online. It is just zip.longest in python 3 and now it works correctly. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Liam87 : I have added a version that uses simple nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use zip to transpose the lists:

```
for vlist in zip(*stacks):
    print ' '.join(vlist)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked however if one list has one more string in it, it will cut off the last string.

Comment: Use izip_longest, as @mhawke suggested